# best_in_place gem: styling OK button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

[best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) is working well but I'd like to use [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) icons for the optional "OK" button, rather than a string. How can I incorporate the `'<i class="icon-ok"></i>'.html_safe` syntax in the `:ok_button` hash?

```
 = best_in_place @book, :default_price_amount, :html_attrs => {:class => 'medium_no_dropdown'}, :ok_button => "OK"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, and the desired functionality is now supported in the best_in_place gem using the :ok_button_class option. Usage is like this:

```
<%= best_in_place @post, :title, :ok_button => "Submit", :ok_button_class => "btn post-title" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution , but not exactly to add a style to the ok_button . If you don't mind to use unicode glyphs , you can try :

```
= best_in_place @book, :default_price_amount, :html_attrs => {:class => 'medium_no_dropdown'}, :ok_button => "&#x2713;".html_safe
```

[The table with all the unicode](http://www.danshort.com/unicode/) characters could be your reference for another variant .

The problem with the real styling of ok_button is that the hash is accepting data-attribute only for defining of the button . Probably in one of the next versions of BIP this will be improved.

In the source code, where the button is created (best_in_place.js):

```
    if(this.okButton) {
    output.append(
      jQuery(document.createElement('input'))
      .attr('type', 'submit')
      .attr('value', this.okButton)
    )
  }
```

'value' is what we pass on the hash . If there is a way to make a reference to the glyph-codes , defined by awesome font (`&#xf00c;` for icon-ok ) , it would be beautiful .

Comment: I just need "html_attrs", Thanks it works like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I spent couple hours to do the same thing, I found that we can override the prototype of [this function](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/bc00bb7912193ea5c9c8984455cb5fe01905e6cb/lib/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js#L356-L375) to create `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">`. However, the [`activateForm` function](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/bc00bb7912193ea5c9c8984455cb5fe01905e6cb/lib/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js#L410) only wait for click event from `input[type="button"]` and since I can't override it, so I try another (a bit dirty) way – and it works.

Overwrite this script at another js tag/files

```
  BestInPlaceEditor.prototype.placeButtons = function (output, field){
    'use strict'
    // the ok button isn't changed
    if (field.okButton) {
      output.append(
        jQuery('<button>').html(field.okButton).attr({
          type: 'submit',
          class: field.okButtonClass
        })
      )
    }

    if (field.cancelButton) {
      // create new cancel "<button>"
      var $resetBtn = jQuery('<button>').html(field.cancelButton).attr({
        type: 'reset',
        class: field.cancelButtonClass
      }),
      // and traditional cancel '<input type="button">', but this should be hidden
      $_resetBtn = jQuery('<input>').val(field.cancelButton).css({ display: 'none' })
      .attr({
        type: 'button',
        class: '__real-btn-close-best_in_place'
      });
      // and bind event to 'trigger' click traditional button when the new <button> is clicked 
      $resetBtn.bind('click', function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).parents('form.form_in_place').find('input.__real-btn-close-best_in_place').trigger('click');
        event.stopPropagation(); // << also neccessary
      });
      // append both
      output.append($_resetBtn).append($resetBtn);
    }
  }
}
```